# System.out.println Not doing what I expect when printing something that evaluates to a boolean

Tags: java

I'm not sure how to describe my question for a title, so here's my code:

```
public class NullLogic {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NullLogic nl = new NullLogic();

        System.out.println("nl.getNull()  = " + nl.getNull() );

        System.out.println("nl.getNull() == null  = " + (nl.getNull() == null) );
        System.out.println("nl.getNull() == null  = " + nl.getNull() == null );


    }


    private String getNull() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Here's the output:

```
nl.getNull()  = null
nl.getNull() == null  = true
false
```

Ok---the first line is no problem, exactly what I'd expect.
Second line is also good.

Now I've got a problem with the third line, I know the statement that evaluates to a boolean should be in brackets, but I figure I should get a runtime error or something, not a successful execution that suppresses the the string part of the sysout.

What's going on here?

This isn't a serious problem that I need to solve, but I don't know what's going on here and I'd like to know.

Thanks!

Comment: Why should you get a runtime error? You're comparing a String (`"nl.getNull() == null  = " + nl.getNull()`) to null, with ==. That's valid Java code.

Comment: See [operator precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Comment: Addition (`+`) has higher priority than equality comparison (`==`)

Comment: ha ha ha. What a dolt! Thanks everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
System.out.println("nl.getNull() == null  = " + nl.getNull() == null )
```

is evaluated as

```
System.out.println(("nl.getNull() == null  = " + nl.getNull()) == null )
```

i.e., first you concatenate two `String`s (the first is not null - `"nl.getNull() == null  = "`, and the second is `null`, but even if both were `null`, concatenating them would result in a not `null` `String`).

The result of this concatenation is the `String`: `"nl.getNull() == null  = null"`.

Then you compare `"nl.getNull() == null  = null"` to `null`, which evaluates to `false`.

Comment: ouch! just not thinking today. Thanks